# Overlapping transparent backgrounds?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a small experiment in which you have a div for the content, which is centered. But I want a transparent box with the same opacity on the left of it. But I can't seem to get it working.

Both backgrounds are set with `background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.74);` and I've googled this issue but I still can't get it to work.

What I want is for `<div class="left"></div>` to have the same (background)color as `<div class="homeheaderblok"></div>`

The reason why `<div class="left"></div>` exists is because of wider screens. And the `<div class="headerblok"></div>` is centered. When shrinking the page, the headerblok overlaps the left.

This:
[image: what I'm trying to accomplish]

is what I'm trying to accomplish. The middle, with the text in it, must overlap the left side when shrinking the page without double opacity.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqttagw4/5/)

Comment: It would be helpful if you had an image of what this is **supposed** to look like because it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I forgot to ask a specific question, my bad. I edited my question.

Comment: Your problem is that the alpha channe;s of 74% (or 0.74) in the `rgba` don't work to make the second 74% of 74% (or 54%)...in fact they work the other way and its 74% divided by 74% and so it's basically 100% Just remove the background from the second div. - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/oqttagw4/4/

Comment: @Paulie_D But now there's no opacity anymore.

Comment: This is why we need an image...

Comment: @Paulie_D I added an background image in the JSFiddle. Here you can properly see my issue. The reason why `<div class="left"></div>` exists is because of wider screens. And the `<div class="headerblok"></div>` is centered. When shrinking the page, the headerblok overlaps the left.

Comment: You're not clarifying the issue. We need to see what this is **supposed** to look like if just removing the background doesn't work. - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/oqttagw4/7/

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't have an image on what it's suppose to look like. That's not the point. The issue is with the double opacity, on what's the best way to remove or get around that.

Comment: It is the point...we (or at least I) can't tell what it is you want from your description. Does the JSfiddle I linked not get you there?

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm sorry for not being clear. Here's a small example I put together: http://i.imgur.com/b73ZQOE.jpg. This what I'm trying to accomplish. The middle, with the text in it, must overlap the left side when shrinking the page without double opacity.

Comment: Doesn't the fiddle I linked do that? - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/oqttagw4/7/

Comment: @Paulie_D No, sorry. Your fiddle removes the background of the content div. It looks good, but on screens bigger then 960px wide, the content has no background.

Comment: Then I suspect you need to re-think the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an additional element for this (if I understood your question right). I would simply take a pseudo-element and extend it to the left. This way, you have no overlapping and it also scales with the screen width:

```css
/* this is the relevant change: */
.headerblok:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";display:block;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.74);
    top:0;right:100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

#header{
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
}

.bigheader{
 height:480px;
 background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/3E5BcB2.jpg');
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.headerblok{
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-480px;
 margin-top:-145px;
 height:290px;
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.74);
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="bigheader">
 <div class="headerblok homeheaderblok">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="headertext">
    <h2>Restauratie en onderhoud</h2>
    <small>Restauratie - Carr&eacute;</small>
    <p>Natuurlijk wordt onze oorsprong nooit verlaten en restaureren wij nog steeds monumenten.</p>
    <div class="aboutinfo">
     Meer hierover<div class="aboutarrow"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[See your modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/oqttagw4/8/)

Comment: Such a small yet sweet example of why css is fantastic. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to get the same color in both regions, the one with the content and the one to the right of it, right?

The problem is that when you are overlapping transparent backgrounds, you see both backgrounds (so the result is less transparent, imagine placing two transparent films on top of each other).

Just remove the background property from .homeheaderblok

Hope it helps.

Comment: I edited my question explaining why `.homeheaderblok` exists.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I don't think there is any easy way of preventing this effect but if there is, I am very curious about it. You will have to work around it by preventing your divs from overlapping.

Answer (score -1):

Hey do change in your css file as mentioned below in one class named 'headerblok'

```
.headerblok{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with positioning. Only the opacity of the background color. All the positions are set.